# How to disable hard drive from BIOS?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I've recently added SSD to my storage drives count and would like to install new OS there, but as I understand if one drive already has boot sector on it, then another (Windows) installation will use same boot sector.

Now I don't know for sure what issues it may raise, so I'd like to prevent it, by disabling current active drive with boot sector.

I know for sure, that manually disabling power supply and SATA cable should help, but could it be done through BIOS, so that there would be no need to do it manually with help of hardware?

Comment: The easiest method would be to physically unplug the drive. If you have your harddrive in a RAID configuration, you will likely destroy the RAID setup if you do this from the bios which causes data loss. A hardware unplug is safe though, given that you plug it back into the same ports.

Comment: And if it is not RAID? One person told me, that it should be safe to disable hard drive from bios. Then new Windows setup should not see the other one.